# In an authentication system using node.js the variable storing verification codes suddenly becomes an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I am trying to build an authentication system and when I save the generated OTP in a variable called verificationcodes it will save, but will become an empty object when verifyOTP function is called. This doesn't happen when testing with postman, but it happens when testing with react-native Android emulator

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const speakeasy = require('speakeasy');
require('dotenv').config();
const verificationCodes = {};
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp-relay.brevo.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
  }
});

const sendEmail = async(emailOptions) => {
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(emailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to send email');
  }
};

const generateOTP = () => {
  return speakeasy.totp({
    secret: speakeasy.generateSecret().base32,
    digits: 6,
    step: 300,
  });
};


const sendVerificationCode = async(email, whatToVerify) => {
  const otp = generateOTP();

  const emailOptions = {
    from: 'Triptrack@triptrack.com.ng',
    to: email,
    subject: 'OTP Verification',
    text: `Hello dear,

Thank you for signing up with TripTrack! Your OTP for email
verification is: ${ otp }.

This OTP will expire in 10 minutes. If you didn't request this, you can safely ignore this email.

Best regards,
The TripTrack Team`,
  };


  verificationCodes[email] = {
    otp,
    expiry: Date.now() + 600000,
    whatToVerify: whatToVerify
  };

  await sendEmail(emailOptions);
  console.log(verificationCodes);
};




//verify

const verifyOTP = (email, otp) => {
  console.log("here====>", verificationCodes);

  if (!verificationCodes[email] ||
    verificationCodes[email].otp !== otp ||
    verificationCodes[email].expiry < Date.now()
  ) {

    return {
      status: false
    };
  }

  //delete verificationCodes[ email ];
  const whatToVerify = verificationCodes[email].whatToVerify;
  return {
    status: true,
    whatToVerify
  };
};

module.exports = {
  sendEmail,
  sendVerificationCode,
  verifyOTP
};
```

Comment: Don't call your users `Dear`. Use their names or Dear plus name. Never use `Dear` on its own

Comment: Is it possible that that backend software e.g. stops and restarts? There's nothing that would persist `verificationCodes` anywhere.

Comment: @AKX no. i am currently building the frontend android and i do not intend to stop the server before the verifyOTP is called. and when i called verifyOTP immidiatly after sending the code from the same file, it logged the correct value

Comment: And you're not e.g. using `pm2` or `nodemon` or anything that might be playing multi-process tricks on you?

Comment: @AKX yes i`m  using nodemon and i just stopped it but still didnt work

Comment: thanks all for your support it actually worked after restarting my laptop. clearly i shouldnt be coding with dell E5430